# ¿Como obtener la ultima parte de una URL de un componente sin el / en reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, rutas

yo en el archivo donde estan mis rutas tengo la ruta

```
path:"/view/:id",
layout: DefaultLayout,
component: viewMore,
```

entonces yo al estar en el navegador puedo tener la ruta http://localhost:3000/view/1 entonces mi pregunta es como obtener el ultimo valor de esa ruta, ese id de la ruta que este en ese momento. hice un intento con window.location.pathname pero con eso obtengo todo el path que es /view/1 y yo necesito solo tener el valor del ultimo dato de la ruta que en ese caso es 1

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya lo resolvi pero para que quede para alguno que lo vaya a necesitar solo use
window.location.pathname.substr(); y ahi define hasta donde quiere obtener el valor